# How to group a group and count the number of elements in this group sql

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in sql and I am wondering how can I get the number of a group in a group. [image]

Here I would like to group the table again according to the column "COL1" and then count the number of elements. This should output at the end that for the group B two is counted and for all others one.

For this first I created a table

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (`ID` INTEGER, `Col1` VARCHAR(1), `Col2` VARCHAR(1), `Col3` VARCHAR(6));

INSERT INTO tablename (`ID`, `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`) VALUES
  ('1', 'A', 'Q', 'green'),
  ('2', 'B', 'R', 'blue'),
  ('3', 'B', 'S', 'red'),
  ('4', 'C', 'T', 'purple'),
  ('5', 'D', 'U', 'orange'),
  ('6', 'E', 'R', 'black'),
  ('7', 'F', 'U', 'brown'),
  ('8', 'F', 'V', 'pink'),
  ('9', 'G', 'W', 'white'),
    ('10', 'B', 'R', 'blue');
```

and then I grouped the columns

```
SELECT count(*),Col1,GROUP_CONCAT(Col2) Col2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Col3) Col3
FROM tablename a
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly what you want

```
select sum(sm),Col1,GROUP_CONCAT(Col2),GROUP_CONCAT(Col3) from (
    SELECT count(*) as sm,Col1,GROUP_CONCAT(Col2) Col2,GROUP_CONCAT(Col3) Col3
    FROM tablename a GROUP BY Col1, Col2
) b GROUP BY Col1
```

Comment: I changed the `sum(sm)` to `count(sm)` and it solved my problem. Thanks!